# How to print last login time?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, bashrc

I'd like to know how to set in `.bashrc` file to print the last login time of users when logging into another user in terminal. I do know that with `who` or `last`, but I'd like something a little more customizable that can be formatted and only runs once per login, preferably to show in a format like so;

```
last login time [ 2015-02-13 @ 3:50:00 AM ]
user@host /path/dir/here $
```

that gets printed to the terminal screen before the bash prompt, and if possible to set and format color on the time and date stamp. How can I achieve this to customizing the bash prompt output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Just as a guideline, the format is not exactly the same):

```
ll=$(last -1 -R  $USER | head -1 | cut -c 20-)
export PS1="last login time [$ll]"'\n\h:\W\$ '
```

Edit: if you want `last` information to be printed only once (wise idea)

```
ll=$(last -1 -R  $USER | head -1 | cut -c 20-)
echo "last login time [$ll]"    # adjust to your login messages, fortunes, etc
export PS1='\n\h:\W\$ '         # replace by your favorite prompt
```

Comment: This works okay… but this doesn't just print that one time after logging in via terminal, it appears after each command is finished. Perhaps there is a way to improve on this answer so it only runs once after logging in.

Comment: There is always space for improvement, that is the goal of SO! (edited)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the following line into your /etc/profile file ...

```
echo "your last login:  `last -1 -R $USER` "
```

This will limit the results to 1 line and report the user's last login, during the login process.  Afterwards it will not re-occur until the next login.

Comment: I'd recommend the user's personal ~/.bashrc file over the system-wide one, in case other users are not interested in such output. Otherwise, this seems to use the code from [JJoao's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184511/117549) and so should be credited there.

Comment: I'm not so interested in who gets the credit but in helping out.  Thanks for pointing that out though.