# Check login history for root user

Tags: shell-script, scripting, security, osx, logs

Following the latest security vulnerability in Mac OS High Sierra, where the root user had no password (seriously, see [this](https://www.wired.com/story/macos-high-sierra-hack-root/)), I'd be curious to find out, if I was a victim of this attack.

How can I get a list of successful logins on the 'root' account, say for the past 30 days?

Have tried the following: [How to print last login time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184506/how-to-print-last-login-time) however that command does not work on High Sierra.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print last login time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184506/how-to-print-last-login-time)

Comment: thanks for pointing out @RomeoNinov. Have updated my question. Does not work on High Sierra.

Comment: @RomeoNinov This maybe a duplicate, but not of that one. That script only is intended to display the time of the last login.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, correct. But it give info how to see the last logins in general. Because the OP did not do even small research how this can be done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see a list of successful logins in MacOS:

- open Terminal
- run the "last" command as in:

  last | grep ^root

You will get a list of the last root logins in reverse chronological order, if any.  To see the entries for all users, just use `last` alone.

Beware a user with root privileges can cover it's tracks.

P.S. the solution from [How to print last login time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184506/how-to-print-last-login-time) does not work in MacOS because the `last`command in MacOS does not support the -R option (at least). Moreover, that answer is only intended to print the time of the last login of *any* user for a linux version of the  `last` command.

Adding to the answer, you can also run the `ac` command:

```
$ac -p
rui        128.40
total      128.40
```

This command will output the sum of time the logged in users were active.

Comment: I have already tried `last`. It only prints `wtmp begins Thu Nov 30 11:53` (current timestamp).

Comment: empty? odd thing - you might try the ac command but I suspect it is just another view in the same data.

Comment: I found the issue, it's because I have to run the command as an administrator.

Comment: I don't know OSX, but on Linux, if `last` reports the last logins (actually the **openings of terminals**), access to files via SFTP doesn't show in its output... And I'm not even sure it shows the logging in of the graphical UI. So IMHO it isn't trustable as a check that the system hasn't been "visited".

Comment: @xenoid This is related to a recent OS/X local flaw (already fixed); root by default cannot ssh/scp